# Generic way to do a search with spring data

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot, I have around 60 entity, some have one to many relation. I search a way to do a generic search to be able to search on any field of thoses entity.

Specification and query dsl are very verbose
Query by example is very limited and spring team don't seem to want to add more fonctionnaly...

any solution to avoid to write a search for every of them?

Answer (score 0):

This is out of scope for Spring Data JPA itself. What you want is search engine. You should look into things like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/) (for which there is [another Spring Data module](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-elasticsearch/)) or [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html)

The idea is that you store your data in the database but you also index it, treating each row, or maybe each entity as a document. You can search that index doing full text search and you'll get back pointers to your database rows.

Comment: i want to search on every field of my entity... not really a search engine

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is confusing What I understand is you want to retrieve/query  data from back end database using each field ,follow this link with same heading inside page,hope it will be helpful

[Creating the Specification Builder Class](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-four-jpa-criteria-queries/)

Comment: you have 800 entity and you need to be able to search of every field of theses entity....  many of this entity have nested entity... how you will avoid to pass you next 6 month to write query to do theses search?